# Referenceerror $ is not defined at onFormSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I am making a script that will check a google form for an answer and then edit a google sheet based on that answer. The script is bound to the form and the code looks like this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var formResponse = e.response;
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
var Weapon = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
var Death = itemResponses[1].getResponse();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f-R8y62j62JmstYPxZ521sJ0wuqKipn1m4puXreeHbc/edit?usp=sharing');
var i = 1;

while (ss.getRange(1, i).getValue() != "")
{
  if (Weapon == ss.getRange(1, i).getValue())
  {
    if (Death == "No") {ss.getRange(2, i).setValue(ss.getRange(2, i).getValue() + 1);}
    else {ss.getRange(3, i).setValue(ss.getRange(3, i).getValue() + 1);}
    break;
  }
}

}
```

But when the code runs I get the error `ReferenceError:R8y62j62JmstYPxZ521sJ0wuqKipn1m4puXreeHbc is not defined at onFormSubmit(Albionscriptmain:9:34)`

At first I thought this was due to access and security problems, but I still receive this error after I made a share link with editorial privileges. It may be that the code is bound to the form? But I bound it to the form to access
`formResponse.getItemResponses();`

I am very new to this but have prior knowledge in programing. Any help and critique is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with the code you provided, are you using some JQuery? Please provide all of your relevant code.

Comment: Try a different form and sheet?

Comment: I made a new form and sheet and still got the same errormessage. Maybe I have not changed enough security restrictions? I clicked the share and selected that everyone with the link can edit.

Comment: Provide screenshot of the error with the code.

Comment: I dont know what more information other than the error message you can get from this.
https://imgur.com/a/uNs8de4

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your code? It is impossible to get the code from  your sheet.

Comment: Right my bad, although the code is written above in its entirety.
https://imgur.com/a/Kvkh3h5

Comment: The difference is your pic uses `openById` and most importantly missed the single quotes `'` around  the id string, which was the cause of this error. Voting to close this as Typo/Not reproducible

Comment: I have been messing around with the security details whilst I was waiting, and it seems like that fixed it. Changing it back from OpenById to OpenByUrl and adding the url made it work. I cant really say why it fixed it but it has to be something with the security settings. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the unclear answer but messing around with the security was the way I fixed this problem. I cant really remember all I did but here is what I can remember:

1. Enable google aps script Api.
2. Creating the link by sharing the sheet with full privileges.

Hope this helps someone who has or have had a similar problem to mine!

Comment: The issue is lack of single quotes `''`. You missed it. So the script thought the id was a variable and caused the reference error. Nothing to do with security.

Comment: The original code had the single quotes though, it looked like this before I changed it later on:

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f-R8y62j62JmstYPxZ521sJ0wuqKipn1m4puXreeHbc/edit?usp=sharing');`

Comment: If the original code had the syntax described in the question, then the code worked without issues as well.